# Read excel files from php

Tags: php, phpexcel

I try to read excel files  with a PHPExcel library. Now I have a 
problem, when upload a file with more of 1000 registers the velocity to insert this to Mysql Data Base is low can 
takes more of 00:01:08 ( 1 min and 8 seconds). Can someone help me whit this issue??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried reading the myriad discussions on performance referenced in the PHPExcel FAQ or on the discussion board? I know that the author (myself) has spent months working on improving speed and memory usage, and providing tools for reading workbooks a a worksheet at a time, or in bite-sized chunks; but there are limits to what can be done... especially with as little information as you provide about how you are using PHPExcel

Comment: I believe tagging is misleading - the question has nothing to do with excel.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: what reader are you using (Excel5 or Excel2007)? Is setReadDataOnly() true or false? Are you reading all worksheet, or just some of them? Are you using a Read Filter? Are you accessing cell data a cell at a time? or are you using the toArray() or rangeToArray() methods to read cell data? There's a lot that can be done; but without knowing what you're doing now, it's hard to help